# Discord bot not playing age restricted videos

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a discord bot that uses YTDL-core to play YouTube videos. Recently I have discovered that it will not play age restricted videos. I was wondering if there is a work around for this. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the javascript.

Comment: I don’t believe it is a code issue because other videos will play.

Comment: You may have configured ytdl in a way that prevents it to play age-restricted videos, so please send the relevant part of your code & the version of ytdl

Answer (score 1):

**Update for 2021**

[Lavalink](https://github.com/freyacodes/Lavalink) fixed the issue with age restriction. Same goes for YTDL ([see commit](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/commit/24297a42efc52862cb9510d32b28efd7faf49af6)).

Comment: Please reiew for readability. I cannot even tell whether you are trying to actually answer. If you are, pleasae try for [answer].